# Attempting to compile and run simple JavaFX class. Error: "javac: invalid flag: --module-path=C:\..."

Tags: java, batch-file, javafx, command-prompt, javac

We have a simple JavaFX HelloWorld Class. I have seen others demonstrate that this code works, so I do not believe that it is the problem. I am running Java and Javac version 1.8.0_291. Java and Javac path environment variables have been set and tested.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;

public class HelloWorldFX extends Application {

    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Label message = new Label("First FX Application!");
        message.setFont( new Font(40) );

        Button helloButton = new Button("Say Hello");
        helloButton.setOnAction( e -> message.setText("Hello World!") );
        Button goodbyeButton = new Button("Say Goodbye");
        goodbyeButton.setOnAction( e -> message.setText("Goodbye!!") );
        Button quitButton = new Button("Quit");
        quitButton.setOnAction( e -> Platform.exit() );

        HBox buttonBar = new HBox( 20, helloButton, goodbyeButton, quitButton );
        buttonBar.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(message);
        root.setBottom(buttonBar);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX Test");
        stage.show();

    } // end start();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);  // Run this Application.
    }

} // end class HelloWorldFX
```

I use a simple `.bat` file to run the compile and run commands. I have also seen others run these batch commands, so I believe they too are written correctly. The module path is a direct copy of the path to the `JavaFX` \lib jars as given by File Explorer, so I believe the path is correct as well. My HelloWorld file is located in the same directory as my `.bat` file that is being run.

```
javac --module-path="C:\Users\14252\Documents\Programming\javafx\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH HelloWorldFX.java
pause
java --module-path="C:\Users\14252\Documents\Programming\javafx\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH HelloWorldFX 
pause
```

Yet, the output is as follows:

console [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XYBn.png) of the `CompileAndRun.bat` file running `javac` and `java` on the `JavaFX` library and the `HelloWorldFX.java` file

Where is this error coming from? How do I correct it?

Comment: java 8 is pre-module..

Comment: Let me try to fill in the missing information in your question. You are using OpenJDK which does not include JavaFX and you downloaded JavaFX 11 from [openjfx](https://openjfx.io/) because they don't have a download link for JavaFX 8. Spoiler: They don't go together. One option is to use [ZuluFX](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?package=jdk-fx) (from _Azul Systems_). Their JDK 8 includes JavaFX. They have 32 bit and 64 bit implementations for several operating systems. Or try one of the other [JDKs](https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/83db09163ca9a0db4c9cd4f91cbf0598).